# Disable GridPanel LoadMask outside Initialization in Ext JS 3.4

Tags: jquery, extjs, extjs3

Is there a way to disable GridPanel's LoadMask outside the initialization config? I know I can do `gridPanel.getView().setLoading(false)` from Ext JS 4 onwards. But is there a solution / workaround for Ext JS 3.4?

Any event on or before `afterrender` should do.

Also, can this be done via jquery? (Given the object hierarchy issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ext.apply(gridPanel,{
  loadMask: false
});
```